# How to fix 'Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting ' in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Thats my Code:

```
library(dplyr)
datanew <- Data %>% 
  group_by(UUID) %>% 
  arrange(-ShapeArea) %>% 
  slice(1)

write.csv(datanew, file = "example.csv")
```

R gives me this error:

```
Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 23466
```

The expecting number is the amount of rows excisting in this data-set.

I've used this Code with similar data-sets and it worked perfectly.

What am I missing?
Thank you!

```
OBJECTID   Gv       Gh            R       UUID             BWF  SPE    BEZSPE NAM OFL BEZOFL ATP BEZATP HHO          DES Z
1       23          1             0     0 DESHPDHK0005Cv9I 1610 0              0          0          0 1000         
2       24          1             0     0 DESHPDHK0005Cv9O 1610 0              0          0          0 1000         
3       25          1             0     0 DESHPDHK0005Cv9U 1610 0              0          0          0 1000         
4       26          1             0     0 DESHPDHK0003OvuK 1205         Tank 1130 Was          0          0          0 4210         
5       27          1             0     0 DESHPDHK0003OvuL 1205         Tank 1130 Was          0          0          0 4210         
6       28          1             0     0 DESHPDHK0003OvuJ 1205         Tank 1130 Was          0          0          0 4210      

 KENN     BEZEICH                                    CRS          SNR       DPRIO B   PR Shape_Length Shape_Area
1 AX51009 AX_SBau                                    ETRS89_UTM32 13042031   290   1  3  1,205862998          0
2 AX51009 AX_SBau                                    ETRS89_UTM32 13042031   290   1  3  16,03426872         10
3 AX51009 AX_SBau                                    ETRS89_UTM32 13042031   290   1  3  5,967865683          2
4 AX51003         AX_VorSp                           ETRS89_UTM32     1305   300   1  3  6,567442635          1
5 AX51003         AX_VorSp                           ETRS89_UTM32     1305   300   1  3  8,642245233          4
6 AX51003         AX_VorSp                           ETRS89_UTM32     1305   300   1  3  34,67721359         30
>
```

Comment: Can you try `as.data.frame(datanew)` and then write

Comment: Unfortunetly this doesn't work, because the error is before the write.csv command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

datanew <- Data
is.data.frame(datanew) 
#if this returns TRUE -> dataframe
#if returns FALSE
datanew <- as.data.frame(datanew)

datanew %>% 
   group_by(UUID) %>% 
   arrange(Shape_Area) %>% 
   slice(1)
write.csv(datanew, file = "example.csv")
```

Comment: This won't work either. Can the error also be the slice command?

Comment: Are you sure datanew is a dataframe? you can check it by doing is.data.frame(datanew). If it is, it will return true

Comment: Probably because datanew isn't defined. try "datanew <- Data" to define it and then  "is.data.frame(datanew)"

Comment: Now it Returns TRUE but still gives out the error after slice command. BTW thank you for your time!

Comment: could you post head(datanew) outcome to your question above? If it's non-sensitive data ofcours :-)

Comment: check my edit. they are all in one row, R seperated them into 2x6 columns. so the dataset is 23466 obs.  of 26 variables

Comment: Your schema says that the column name is "Shape_Area" and not "ShapeArea" like in your code?

Comment: That's Right! I'm sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :-)